# Continuous Integration for Intersystems Cache solutions

Tags: java, continuous-integration, intersystems-cache, intersystems

I am starting a project from scratch using Intersystems Cache. I would like to setup a Continuous Integration Server for the project. Cache has unit test libraries, so the idea is to import source into a test database, build the source, run unit tests in the cache terminal, based on changes in the version control system (ClearCase).

Apart from Cache Objectscript, there will definitely be some java code that needs to be built as well. Other technologies could be added later. So I need a Continuous Integration tool that is not bound to one specific technology and that is easily extendible. I have used CruiseControl for building java solutions in the past, but that has been quite some time ago and I am wondering if no better solution is available since.

What is the best (and hopefully free) Continuous Integration product, that is easiest to extend for different technologies?

Comment: If I could remove this question I would. avoiding this tech at all cost in the future and no, I'm not talking about CI :-) (just my two cents)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'd recommend looking at [Hudson](http://hudson-ci.org/).  It's insanely easy to try out as it is delivered as an executable jar.  It also supports [plugins](http://hudson.gotdns.com/wiki/display/HUDSON/Extend+Hudson) so it may be better suited to extension and customization.  There are also a good deal of very handy plugins for Hudson [already out there](http://hudson.gotdns.com/wiki/display/HUDSON/Plugins).  Its ClearCase support comes via a plugin.  There's even a plugin to start and stop VMWare virtual machines from within your build process which may be of interest depending on how you're planning on handling your database server "needs."

Comment: Hudson is awesome, and it's very flexible.

Comment: Second the motion for Hudson - recently migrated my long-standing CruiseControl builds into Hudson with stellar results, and outstanding feedback from developers and other users.

Comment: Thanks, I have tried out hudson for a bit and I must say that I was pleasantly surprised!

Answer (score 1):

I have built a makeshift Continuous Integration Server in the following screencast: http://www.ensemblisms.com/episodes/2

Answer (score 0):

Raymond Roestenburg!!

I am currently testing a stack for continuous integration of our solution is developed in Caché , the stack I'm testing now includes versioning source code using Git + TortoiseGit (with a plugin called "cache-tort-git "https://github.com/intersystems-ru/cache-tort-git/wiki specific to Caché ) for local versioning and BitBucket for remote versioning.

For continuous integration I'm using the Jenkins (evolution of the Hudson) , with a job that downloads the updated source code and after runs a COS script that does the following tasks:

1. Compiles all the source code;
2. Compiles all CSP rules;
3. Compiles all CSP pages;
4. Run all unit tests;
5. Run all integration tests;